# Single sign on for .Net and java application which are on different domain

Tags: java, .net, cookies, spring-security, single-sign-on

I have 2 web applications one is in .Net and one in Java. I have to create single sign on facility between these 2 applications, I have created using cookies referring old questions from stack overflow. But it will not work if on browser cookies are disabled. Need better solution than cookies which should be secure too.

Answer (score 0):

The standards based approach to achieve Web SSO could be SAML (http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf). Spring SAML security extension would make it fairly easy to integrate your Java based app. If you have .Net your may also have ADFS, which can act as a SAMLv2 IdP.

WS-Federation is more common in Microsoft env, however I'm not sure there is a nice lib/framework available in Java space.

You may also have a look at OAuth2. Actually it was designed to protect APIs but you can also use it to achieve Web SSO.